# Filestream shared folder permission issues

Tags: sql, filestream, filetable

I'm trying to drag and drop a file from my desktop to my local MSSQLSERVER shared folder/directory used for filestream files. Everytime I do so, I receive the following Windows error - "You need permission to perform this action."

I feel like I've tried everything under the sun to resolve this, from adding users and groups to the share's permission list (and granting full access) -- all the way to adjusting permission settings in SQL Server (for the database and individual filetable).

My local MSSQLServer service is logged on as a network account and I'm trying to drag/drop with my windows authenticated account. I've tried modifying so the service so it's logged on by a windows auth account, restarted, but still no luck there.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You tried to enable the "Allow remote clients to have streaming access to FILESTREAM data" in SQL Server Configuration Manager | SQL Server Services | SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) | FILESTREAM?

Tried to change the ownership Filestream Access Level:
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2
RECONFIGURE
(0 - disabled, 1 - T-SQL access enabled and 2 - full access enabled [including access via windows explorer].)

(http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/sql-server-2008-filestream-part-2-of-3-enabling-and-using-filestream-2/)

PS: Sorry for my english.